# Use different version of kafka - 0.8.2.2 and 0.10.1 API in same application

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have java application that consumes data from Kafka and pushes the consumed data to the database. It currently is based on Kafka 0.8.2 API. Is it possible to (dynamically/statically) select/create consumer using either version 0.8.2 or 0.10.2 to provide the functionality?

Currently the application is using the following kafka classes: kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig, kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator, kafka.consumer.KafkaStream, kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector, kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you run two versions of the same library in your application (not only Kafka), then you will get `NoSuchMethodError` exception.